# printing in 2 printers at the same time

Tags: printing

Hi I am having 2 printers with same name/ driver Samsung c460) and both are shared, if I am giving print job to one printer it is coming through another one also which is printing in both the printers same time. How do I separate both the printers?

Comment: post results of `lpstat -t` please. and if the printers have the same name rename one.

Answer (score 0):

See what works for me:

1. delete the both printers... and turn all off
2. click on install a new printer... and turn the first one on
   see that printer appear on device list. Install it but on device name put something like "Printer-01" and repeat it on description.
3. do the same in second printer but now put "Printer-02" in name and repeat on description

Easy and works for me.